# Can't display selected property from NGRX state

Tags: angular, state, ngrx

I'm trying to display error from state, it's `Observable<String>` type so I'm using `async` pipe.

In component

```
this.error = store.select(state => state.error); // in constructor
error: Observable<String>;
```

In template:

```
<div *ngIf="error | async as err">
  <p>{{ err }}</p>
</div>
```

I have almost the same code at another component, it works, here it doesn't. I see the error on devtools, it's there.

Comment: try `this.error = store.select(state => state.error).pipe(startWith("is it really there?"))`

Comment: I didn't notice that I had imported the state interface instead of real state. Thank you, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet seems alright, make sure you:

- mutate state in a *pure* way, no direct assignments (do not do `state.error = errorMessage`)
- verify there's an `error` property that exists on the state

Comment: I imported the state interface instead of state, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="error | async; let err">
  <p>{{ err }}</p>
</div>
```

this should be working (if you don't have any errors befuor this.error = store.select(state => state.error); // in constructor
error: Observable;